# How to call another shell script from a shell script in Unix

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to call another shell script from inside a shell script in unix (bash)

1st Shell script(script_1.sh):

```
VARIABLE_1=<VALUE>
<unix_code> 
<unix_code>
..
..
..
export VARIABLE_1
bash -x script_2.sh
bash -x script_3.sh
```

my requirement here is to pass the value of VARIABLE_1 to script_2.sh & script_3.sh. I was able to execute script_2.sh pass the argument to script_2.sh and it was working fine. Problem has started when i included script_3.sh. It gives me below error, when i execute the first shell script.

```
/usr/bin/sh: /usr/bin/sh: cannot execute binary file
```

Not sure why this happening. Also, Is this recommended way to pass arguments and call other shell scripts ? Please let me know

Comment: Does script_3.sh run properly when executed outside of script_1.sh?

Comment: Check that you can run `/usr/bin/sh` from the command-line.  It looks like `script_3.sh` makes a call to `/usr/bin/sh` somewhere.

Comment: Can you show the full error output, in particular the `xtrace` (`-x`) output immediately preceding the error?

Answer (score 2):

`cannot execute binary file` does not mean the file lacks execute permissions. In fact, running a script as "bash filename", does not need the executable permissions on the filename.

The error message is telling you that the script file is not an actual script file, but a binary file, probably an executable. If that is the case, do not do:

```
bash +x filename
```

just do:

```
filename
```

Additionally, to pass arguments to the script, you can do so like this:

`scriptfile arg1 arg2 arg3`

then refer inside your script as `$1`, `$2`, `$3`. Or `$*`to refer to all of them.

EDIT:

Also note that to execute a script you do not need to use `bash scriptfile`, you may just run `scriptfile`. In that case, scriptfile must have the executable permission (i.e., `chmod +x scriptfile`). Additionally, if the file is in the current directory, but the `.` is not part of the `PATH`variable, the scriptfile will not be found. In that case you should execute your scriptfile as `./scriptfile`

Your script would change to:

```
VARIABLE_1=<VALUE>
...
./script_2.sh "$VARIABLE_1"
./script_3.sh "$VARIABLE_1"
```

You no longer need to export the VARIABLE_1. The quotes are necessary to make sure the contents of VARIABLE_1 are passed as a single argument. script_2.sh and script_3.sh will see the value as `$1`. If the VARIABLE_1 has spaces in it, and you omit the quotes, each word will be pass as a separate value. That is, `$1` will have the first word, `$2`the second, etc.

Comment: I think the error message means that `/usr/bin/sh` cannot be executed.  If it was the script name then it would say `script_3.sh: script_3.sh cannot execute binary file`

Comment: I wonder what the script_3.sh contents are. Maybe the error message is coming from something executed inside script_3.sh, not from the actual call of script_3.sh

Comment: that's my guess, but the OP has not answered my questions

Answer (score -1):

script_3.sh may not have permission to execute.  Use chmod to provide appropriate permission and try again